# How to enable verbose logging to the console with puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I have a nodejs app that uses puppeteer to take screenshots. I have enabled the `dumpio` setting when launching puppeteer, so that the content of the browser console is dumped to my console (nodejs app):

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    dumpio: true
  });
```

This works fine, but I would like to gather **ALL** messages that you can see in Chrome devtool's console, such as network requests.

There is a [Debugging Tips](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#debugging-tips) section in the docs that indicates that is should be possible:

> 6. Enable verbose logging - internal DevTools protocol traffic will be logged via the debug module under the puppeteer namespace.

> ```
>  # Basic verbose logging
>  env DEBUG="puppeteer:*" node script.js
>
>  # Protocol traffic can be rather noisy. This example filters out all Network domain messages
>  env DEBUG="puppeteer:*" env DEBUG_COLORS=true node script.js 2>&1 | grep -v '"Network'
> ```

But when I set the environment variable `DEBUG="puppeteer:*"` in my nodejs app, I do not get that extra info logged to the console.

Is there something that I'm missing or that I'm not doing right?

Comment: Weird, I do get the extra info with the env var, both on my x64 Macbook pro (Node v17.0 and HeadlessChrome/93.0.4577.0) and on aarch64 Ubuntu 20 server (Node v14.17 and chromium-browser 95.0.4638.69)

Comment: Actually, I haven't got back to this, but one thing I noticed is that when debugging with VSCode, the output of my console was getting swallowed somehow. I'll have to retry without the debugger attached again